# Mac text editor that can colour chunks of code?

Tags: colors, text-editors, textmate

I'm an avid Textmate user and for the job I'm working on could really do with highlighting large chunks of code. It's a proper soup at the moment and it would be great if I could highlight a chunk and colour it for reference.

If there's not a way to do it in Textmate does anyone know of a code editor that might do what I'm looking for?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Would sound like a useful addition. So far I've seen in emacs you can express regions to be hightlighted by `highlight-regexp` or using `font-lock` keywords. Using that one could introduce some keywords to mark regions. But I have problems finding the regexp that will work over multiple lines.

Comment: If bookmarks in TextMate aren't enough, have a look at the bundles -- you could try to edit the bundle you're using for syntax highlighting and language-specific commands to include your custom highlighting.